# Conflito de CSS no index

Tags: css, css3

Tenho a página abaixo com um erro de `css`:

http://hotplateprensas.com.br/gasmuriae.com.br2/

Nela tem uma `div` com a `classe` topo e dentro dessa `div` tenho 3 `div's`:

```
<div class="topo">

  <div class="topoTel" id="topoTel"><img src="_img/sgb.png" /></div>

  <div class="topoMeio" id="topoMeio"><h1><?php echo $constantes->getWwwSite(); ?></h1></div>

  <div class="topoRedesSociais" id="topoRedesSociais">
    <img class="face" src="_img/facebook.png" />
    <img class="insta" src="_img/instagram.png" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Para economizar código que estava assim,

```
 div.topo div.topoTel, 
 div.topo div.topoMeio, 
 div.topo div.topoRedesSociais {
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
     vertical-align:middle;
     width: 33%;
 }
```

fiz assim:

```
 div.topo div {
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
     vertical-align:middle;
     width: 33%;
 }
```

Mas, se olharem  na página na web, verão que o **layout** do topo está bagunçado. 
Parece que foi trocado de `inline-block` para `block` o display das `div's` internas.

Como pode ser visto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ao passo de que o correto seria como abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, fiz uma página,

http://hotplateprensas.com.br/gasmuriae.com.br2/topo.php

Só com a parte do topo. E para minha surpresa, o erro não ocorreu!

Estou a um tempão procurando o conflito e pela minha pouca experiência com css, não estou encontrando e peço a ajuda de vocês.

Comment: Notei que na página onde só tem o topo não possui uma div com a classe "sessoes" que tem no site completo.

Comment: Retirando a `<div class="sessoes">` o problema se resolve.

Comment: entendi. Fiz uma adaptação e coloquei  div.topo div:not(div.sessoes) {}. E, ele transformou as divs em diplay:block, uma embaixo da outra. De fato, como as 3 div's estavam dentro da div.sessoes e a div sessoes estava dentro da div.topo, o style acabou transformando ela em 33% também.Mas não posso tirar a div.sessoes pois ela quem dá tamanho ao body. Seerá que existe uma forma de fazer  div.topo div:not(div.sessoes) {} de forma que os filhos da div.sessoes não sejam afetados pelo .not()?

Comment: bota um `display: block; width: 100%;` nessa div sessoes.

Comment: não posso, ela vai me dar 1000px que preciso. Não posso mexer nisso!

Comment: não pode botar então `display: block; width: 1000px;`?

Comment: Não, senão vão ter 3 linhas. O cansaço faz coisas. Achei a solução que estava bem na minha frente:  div.topo div.sessoes div {}